# how to make same build for all android device using Accelerometer

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing the game using Accelerometer (Andengine) .

Sample code:

```
this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    final Engine engine = new Engine(new EngineOptions(true,ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new  FillResolutionPolicy(), this.mCamera).setNeedsSound(true));  

if(pAccelerometerData.getX()<-1)
// Move ball in upwards direction

else if (pAccelerometerData.getX()>1)  
 // Move ball in dowards direction
```

Its working fine in HTC g1 device (320x480). But when i trying to run in samsung b7510 (320x240) and galaxy tablet, I need to rotate acclometer in reverse direction. For that problem i made

```
if(pAccelerometerData.getY()<-1)
// Move ball in upwards direction

else if (pAccelerometerData.getY()>1)  
 // Move ball in dowards direction
```

How to make same build for all device using Accelerometer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that some devices are portrait mode by default, and some are landscape by default. The y axis of the accelerometer is aligned to the "up" direction of the device in its natural state, which changes from device to device. On a regular portrait-by-default phone, the y axis is aligned to the longest side of the screen:

```
 +------+
 |      |    ^
 |      |   y|
 |      |    |
 |      |    |
 |      |    +---->
 |      |        x
 +------+
```

But on a tablet, or a wide phone that is landscape by default, the y axis is aligned to the shortest side of the screen.

```
 +--------------+
 |              |    ^
 |              |   y|
 |              |    |
 +--------------+    +------->
                            x
```

The solution is to check [android.view.Display.getRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29). On a portrait device that is in its default orientation (i.e. like the fist ASCII art diagram) this will return `ROTATION_0`. On a landscape device turned so it is with the longest part of the screen pointing up it will return `ROTATION_90` (or `ROTATION_270`).

Similarly, if you force your game to be in landscape mode with `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in the AndroidManifest.xml or via `ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE` as in your snippet, then a portrait phone will return `ROTATION_90` and a landscape device `ROTATION_0`.

In the case of a forced landscape game you would need something like this:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(
                                     Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
boolean portrait = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90;
// ...
float dy;
if (portrait) {
    dy = pAccelerometerData.getX();
} else {
    dy = pAccelerometerData.getY();
}
if (dy < -1) {
    // move ball up
} else if (dy > 1) {
    // move ball down
}
```

This is only for Android 2.2 and later. Earlier devices were all portrait, and the `getRotation()` method does not exist, so you'll have to use reflection or similar techniques if you want to support devices that haven't got Froyo.

Comment: I used                                                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);   
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();        
   int  portrait=display.getRotation();   if (portrait == Surface.ROTATION_90 || portrait == Surface.ROTATION_270) {//landscape  } else {-portrait-}